# Spark SQL Query to Compare two Spark Dataframes using Spark Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes. Input dataframe which i am reading from Kafka and the other one i am reading from DB2 database.

NOTE: I am using Spark Java to code.

The requirement is :

E.g.

```
INPUT_DF

ID  NAME    CITY        DATE
----------------------------------  <In comparison to BASE_DATAFRAME>
111 aaa     ATLANTIC    20200201    <New ID>
222 bbb     PACIFIC     20200202    <ID Exist, Later DATE, NAME different>
333 bbb     INDIAN      20200201    <ID Exist, Earlier DATE>
444 NNN     CORAL       20200205    <ID Exist, Earlier DATE, ALL OTHER COLUMNS SAME VALUE>
555 bbb     INDIAN      20200206    <ID Exist, Later DATE, ALL OTHER COLUMNS SAME VALUE>
666 aaa     ATLANTIC    20200201    <New ID>
```

```
BASE_DATAFRAME from DB2 TABLE

ID  NAME    CITY        DATE
----------------------------------
222 CCC     PACIFIC     20200201
333 bbb     ATLANTIC    20200203
444 NNN     CORAL       20200206
555 bbb     INDIAN      20200202
```

Result 1:

```
ID  NAME    CITY        DATE
----------------------------------
111 aaa     ATLANTIC    20200201
666 aaa     ATLANTIC    20200201
```

Result 2:

```
ID  NAME    CITY        DATE
----------------------------------
222 bbb     PACIFIC     20200202
```

Please help me with the queries to get the results.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain how you got result 1 and result 2
Also, what are you trying to actually achieve here?
The question is just incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution..
Used below queries to get both the results.

```
Result 1:
spark.sql("SELECT f.* FROM INPUT_DF f LEFT JOIN BASE_DATAFRAME s ON f.ID=s.ID WHERE s.ID is NULL");

Result 2:
spark.sql("SELECT f.* FROM INPUT_DF f JOIN BASE_DATAFRAME s ON f.ID=s.ID WHERE f.DATE>s.DATE and (f.name<>s.name OR f.city<>s.city)");
```